# Get mimetype from byte array without external lib

Tags: java, arrays, mime-types

Someone know one method to get the mime type from byte array? Attention, i want to do that without external library, only native java.

Comment: Are you asking to inspect the bytes in an array and try to determine what kind of file it is and thus associate it with a mime type?

Comment: @MattBall: Actually it's a common practive to do so. The first x bytes in a byte array (contents of a file) are often 'magic bytes' which uniquely identifies the type of the byte array.

Oh, and I don't think it's possible in plain java. You should take a look at Apache Tika (yes, an external library..): http://tika.apache.org/

Comment: @Jan yes, it's the "without external libraries" part...

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do that using Java 7, but it is kind of clumsy (um tanto "desajeitado"):

- write the bytes to a (temporary) file,
- use `Files.probeContentType(Path)` to check the contents of that file

if the bytes came from a file you could use probeContentType directly on it.

---

EDIT:
not very useful, at least on Windows: `probeContentType` seams to primarily use the file extension to determine the file type [:-|